# ¿Cómo obtener el máximo de los resultados de un count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT li.nombre, 
       count(li.cantidad) as cantidad
  FROM LINEA
 GROUP BY li.nombre
```

La consulta me devuelve estos datos:

```
Coca      19
Corona    9
Mandarina 12
Speed     8
```

Necesito una consulta que me devuelva el máximo. En este caso la consulta debería devolverme:

```
Coca - 19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tan sencillo como hacer un *order by* ordenando de mayor a menor con *DESC* y sacar sólo la primera línea con *top/limit* ;-)

Para **SQL Server**:

```
SELECT TOP 1 li.nombre, count(li.cantidad) as cantidad
FROM linea li
GROUP BY li.nombre
ORDER BY cantidad DESC;
```

Para otras bases de datos que no soporten TOP

```
SELECT li.nombre, count(li.cantidad) as cantidad
FROM linea li
GROUP BY li.nombre
ORDER BY cantidad DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: La primera me anduvo bien ya que uso SQL Server! muchas gracias!